# Как изменить раскладку клавиатуры?

Tags: linux, клавиатура, archlinux, xorg

[Типографская раскладка Ильи Бирмана](https://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/) доступна только для Mac и Windows. Мне из нее достаточно всего четырех символов:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>: — (длинное тире, `&mdash`);
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>: − (минус);
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>: « (левая кавычка, `&laquo;`);
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>: » (правая кавычка, `&raquo;`).

*<sub>Слева — комбинация клавиш, справа — получившийся символ.</sub>*

На данный момент я переключаюсь между русской и английской раскладкой следующим образом:

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us,ru -variant , -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Как я могу изменить раскладки клавиатуры (и `us` и `ru`) так, чтобы печатались необходимые символы при нажатии соответствующей комбинации клавиш?

Перечитал кучу манов, в том числе [Keyboard configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration) и [X keyboard extension](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension), но так и не понял, как можно это сделать.

Comment: Если можно обойтись просто доступностью этих символов с клавиатуры — повесьте их на compose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Типографская раскладка Ильи Бирмана доступна только для Mac и Windows.

На самом деле в `xkb` в одной из своих версии она идёт из коробки. Включается:

```
setxkbmap -option misc:typo
```

Также к этому нужно добавить клавишу для выбора третьего ряда (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>), назначить её можно, например на правый <kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_switch
```

После этого <kbd>R_Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> будет давать длинное тире (`—`), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R_Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> — среднее (`–`) и т.д.

В гуёвых конфигураторах эти опции называются соответственно как-то так:

- Misc/Enable extra typographic characters
- Key to choose 3rd level/Right Alt

---

Также можно по-класически настроить клавишу [Compose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose), например на правую Super-клавишу:

```
setxkbmap -option compose:rwin
```

Ввод тире будет выглядеть как **последовательное** нажатие клавиш:

<kbd>Rwin</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd> → —

Другие комбинации можно посмотреть в той же вике.

Из минусов такого подхода можно отметить то, что для ввода многих символов, как кавычки-ёлочки придётся переключаться на английскую раскладку.

---

Ни кто не спрашивал, но ещё раз хочу прорекламировать переключение раскладки по <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>'у; положение оной под мизинцем крайне упрощает жизнь:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:caps_toggle
```

---

> Как я могу изменить раскладки клавиатуры (и us и ru) так, чтобы печатались необходимые символы при нажатии соответствующей комбинации клавиш?

Это достаточно геморройно и AFAIK нормальных способов это сделать нет. Если кратко, то редактировать их придётся вручную где-то в `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru`.

Answer (score 2):

Маленькое дополнение к ответу @FatZer:
я использую примерно такой .XCompose (чтобы иметь кавычки-лапки, и чтобы кавычки-ёлочки работали и в русской раскладке, помимо прочего):

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"                                                                                                                                       
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <apostrophe> : "́" U0301 # ударение                                                                                                                               
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_e> <Cyrillic_e> : "́" U0301 # ударение                                                                                                                               

# COMBINING SIGNS, модифицирующие знаки (меняют предыдущий символ)                                                                                                                        
<Multi_key> <v> <v> : "⃗" U20D7 # знак вектора                                                                                                                                             
<Multi_key> <z> <z> : "̶" U0336 # зачёркивание                                                                                                                                             
<Multi_key> <v> <i> : "̅" U0305 # COMBINING OVERLINE, vinculum, надчёркивание                                                                                                              

# Удобная пунктуация в русской раскладке                                                                                                                                                  
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_be> <Cyrillic_be> : "„" # открывающая кавычка-лапка (RUS)                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_yu> <Cyrillic_yu> : "“" # закрывающая кавычка-лапка (RUS)                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_io> <Cyrillic_io> : "“" # закрывающая кавычка-лапка (RUS)                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <slash> <slash> : "«" # открывающая кавычка-ёлочка (RUS)                                                                                                                      
<Multi_key> <bar> <bar> : "»" # закрывающая кавычка-ёлочка (RUS)                                                                                                                          
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_BE> <Cyrillic_BE>: "«" # открывающая кавычка-ёлочка (RUS)                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_YU> <Cyrillic_YU>: "»" # закрывающая кавычка-ёлочка (RUS)                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_ya> : "̶" # зачеркивание (комбинирующееся)                                                                                                                           
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_e> <Cyrillic_e> : "́" # ударение (комбинирующееся)                                                                                                                  
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_i> <Cyrillic_i> : "і" U0456 # украинская «i»                                                                                                                        
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_I> <Cyrillic_I> : "І" U0406 # украинская «i»                                                                                                                        
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_i> <colon> : "ї" U0457 # украинская «ї»                                                                                                                             
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_I> <colon> : "Ї" U0407 # украинская «Ї»                                                                                                                             
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_i> <Cyrillic_ZHE> : "ї" U0457 # украинская «ї»                                                                                                                      
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_I> <Cyrillic_ZHE> : "Ї" U0407 # украинская «Ї»                                                                                                                      
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_IE> <Cyrillic_IE> : "Є" U0404 # украинская «Ї»                                                                                                                      
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_ie> <Cyrillic_ie> : "є" U0454 # украинская «є»                                                                                                                      
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_u> <Cyrillic_u> : "ў" U040E                                                                                                                                         
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_U> <Cyrillic_U> : "Ў" U045E                                                                                                                                         
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_hardsign> <Cyrillic_hardsign> : "ѣ" U0463 # ять
```

Удобно.

Comment: а у меня такой [`~/.XCompose`](http://dpaste.com/2JSKXZ6)

Comment: @Fat-Zer у меня тоже. Неочевидно вышло, согласен. Менять уж не буду.